# Trying to cycle through objects in an array using keyboard input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to implement some basic functionality in Unity using this script attached to an empty which has 6 child objects. I have tried various fixes in my code, but cant seem to achieve the desired result.

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class ObjectSelector : MonoBehaviour
{
// This array stores the Prefabs
public GameObject[] ObjectArray;

// Integer for stepping through array Prefabs
private int selectedObject = 0;

// Location to instantiate the prefab
private Transform locator;

// Holds the currently instantiated Prefab in the scene
private GameObject tempMesh;

void Start()
{
    // Instantiate initial Prefab
    tempMesh = Instantiate(ObjectArray[selectedObject], locator.position, locator.rotation);
}



void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {

        // Step to next position in array
        ObjectArray++; 

        // Remove previously instantiated prefab from hierarchy
        Destroy(tempMesh);

        // Instantiated next Prefab
        tempMesh = Instantiate(ObjectArray[selectedObject], locator.position, locator.rotation);

        // Print Counter for debug
        print(ObjectArray);

        // If Array count excedes Array index then go back to first position in array
        if (ObjectArray >= ObjectArray.Length)
        {
            ObjectArray = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what is the error or unexpected result/

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing an array, you need to increment your counter

```cs
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        // Step to next position in array
        selectedObject++; 

// If Array count exceeds Array index then go back to first position in array
        if (selectedObject >= ObjectArray.Length)
        {
            selectedObject = 0;
        }

        // Remove previously instantiated prefab from hierarchy
        Destroy(tempMesh);

        // Instantiated next Prefab
        tempMesh = Instantiate(ObjectArray[selectedObject], locator.position, locator.rotation);

        // Print Counter for debug
        print(selectedObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, that was indeed the issue. unfortunately now I am experiencing an issue with Unity where I am getting Object not set to instance of object error now.

Comment: @JK make another question, with the error, code and a screenshot

Comment: thanks for your help dean, I actually figured it out!